# Element type changes in type array Any

Tags: swift

How to change the type to `Int` for an element in an array of type `Any`

Waited for it to work but no

```
var arr: Any = [9, 3, "7", "3"]
var arrInt = arr.map{ $0 as! Int } // Value of type 'Any' has no member 'map'
```

Comment: `var arrInt = arr.compactMap{ $0 as? Int }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Value of type 'Any' has no member 'compactMap'

Comment: Dont set the type explicitly. Just use `[Any]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, the fact is that I would like to know what to do in this particular situation

Comment: You declared your array as `Any`, not `[Any]`. Thus the system does not know that it is an array at all. Don't you mean to have `var arr: Array<Any> = [9, 3, "7", "3"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert your values to Int you will need to try to cast your element to Int and in case it fail you need to cast from Any to String and initialize a new integer from it:

```
let arr: [Any] = [9, 3, "7", "3"]
let arrInt = arr.compactMap { $0 as? Int ?? Int($0 as? String ?? "") }
arrInt  // [9, 3, 7, 3]
```

If you really want to declare your object as `Any` you will need to cast it to array before trying to iterate its elements:

```
let arr: Any = [9, 3, "7", "3"]
let arrInt = (arr as? [Any])?.compactMap { $0 as? Int ?? Int($0 as? String ?? "") } ?? []
arrInt  // [9, 3, 7, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Leo's chain of `??` nil coalescing operators is clever, but a little hard to follow. A longer way to write the same sort of conversion that I think is clearer:

```
var arr: [Any] = [9, 3, "7", "3", 1.34, "Lorem ipsum"]

let newArray: [Int] = arr.compactMap {
    switch $0 {
    case let anInt as Int:
        return anInt
    case let string as String:
        return Int(string)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
print(newArray)
```

prints `[9, 3, 7, 3]`